# ODD ERROR: System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

I use asp.net 4 c# entity framework 4 and asp.net membership.

I usually use VS2010 CASSINI as to test my web application.. now I have to move my web app to IIS 7 locally.

My app was working just fine on Cassini, now on IIS 7 when some script try to access asp.net membership table I get this error:

```
System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'. However, the current database schema is not compatible with this version. You may need to either install a compatible schema with aspnet_reqsql.exe (available in the framework installation directory), or upgrade the provider to a newer version. Alright, my database was exactly the same and everything looked fine.
```

I tied to recycle pool and website but the problem persist.

Do you have any ideas? Many thanks for your time no this.

UPDATE:

I found out this line in the SQL script with generate the DB ... could be connected?:

```
xp_cmdshell 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S localhost -A mr -Q -d SiteNameExtension' -- mr = install Membership, Role Manager
```

Comment: Sounds like you're missing data in the ASP.NET membership tables.

Answer (score 0):

This line in my sql installation script created the problem:

```
xp_cmdshell 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S localhost -A mr -Q -d SiteNameExtension' -- mr = install Membership, Role Manager
```

In fact aspnet_regsql.exe was not targeting Framework Version as in my Web.Configure (it was 4).

Updating xp_cmdshell o the right Framework version i solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the web config file with correct version of System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider

You can find the below configuration in c:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/v4.0.30319 or any other version , there you can find config file . Into it check for machine config files
to get version & public key.

For .net frameowork 4.0

```
     <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
     <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" connectionStringName="rolesDB" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
     </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

for .net framework 2.0

```
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
     <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" connectionStringName="rolesDB" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
     </providers>
  </roleManager>
```